# How can I change all the device IDs on my quad port Intel NIC?

Tags: networking, ethernet

So I have a quadport Intel gigabite NIC (dual 82571EB).

To get the device IDs, I used:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ lspci -nn -vvv | grep Ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
```

all the 4 devices were identified as 8086:10bc. **I want to change 10bc to 105e for all 4 devices.**

ifconfig shows all 4 devices as:

```
enp3s0f0 enp3s0f1 enp4s0f0 enp4s0f1
```

To find the correct offset, I used this command:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -e my-interface-here | grep 86

0x0010 87 d9 05 71 2f 24 4b 70 3c 10 bc 10 86 80 65 b3
```

Running the command above for all 4 interfaces gave me the same result.

I made a backup of the EEPROM for all interfaces using:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -e my-interface-here raw on > my-interface-here.bin
```

To actually make the change, I used this command:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -E enp3s0f0 magic 0x10bc8086 offset 0x001a value 0x001a value 0x5e
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -E enp3s0f1 magic 0x10bc8086 offset 0x001a value 0x001a value 0x5e
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -E enp4s0f0 magic 0x10bc8086 offset 0x001a value 0x001a value 0x5e
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -E enp4s0f1 magic 0x10bc8086 offset 0x001a value 0x001a value 0x5e
```

**Observations/issues:**

After rebooting machine, I ran

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ lspci -nn -vvv | grep Ethernet
    xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ lspci -nn -vvv | grep Ethernet
    03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
    03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:105e] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:000a]
    04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
    04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:105e] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:000a]
```

and it shows only 2 device IDs have changed.

I moved the network cable to all 4 ports and I can browse the internet without any problems. This happened after rebooting.

Any suggestions on how to change all device IDs to 105e? thanks

Comment: To prevent X-Y problems: **Why** do you want to change the ID. What is your goal? Is it having another driver attach itself?

Comment: Also, not sure this is about [networking] or [Ethernet]. Just which tag is fitting is a big question.  Flashing firmware nic?

Comment: I want to change the device ID for better driver support. I was only using Xubuntu/Linux since ethtool is the only command I know that can do it for me.

Comment: Why not change the driver instead? I mostly use BSD, but I am reasonably sure that where is a device ID check in linux drivers as well. And you could add your PCI-e devices ID there. No need to flash or change the NIC in any way.